# Generic Method with different argument but same return type

Tags: java, generics, class-design

I have multiple methods which accept different types in arguments but have the same return type. I am planning to create a generic method but not sure of the implementation.

Method 1 :

```
private Details mapStudentDetails(final Student student) {
        return Details.builder()
            .line1(student.getLine1())
            .line2(student.getLine2())
            .postcode(student.getPostcode())
            .country(student.getCountryCode())
            .build();
    }
```

**UPDATED Method 2 :**

```
private Details mapTeacherDetails(final Teacher teacher) {
        return Details.builder()
            .line1(teacher.getAddressLine1())
            .line2(teacher.getAddressLine2())
            .postcode(teacher.getZipCode())
            .country(teacher.getCountryCode())
            .build();
    }
```

How can I implement a generic method for this usecase ?

```
private Details mapDetails ( T type) {
}
```

Comment: you should make an abstract  class Person and define all the common methods of Teacher and Student then extend it

Comment: `Student` and `Teacher` need to implement a common interface, (say `HasDetails`) which has all the methods you call (`getLine1`, ..., `getCountryCode`). You don't need a generic method, just make the parameter type `HasDetails`.

Comment: An interface might suffice, and you needs the following methods: `getLine1()`, `getLine2()`, `getPostcode()`, `getCountryCode()`. It may even be possible to add the method as `Details.fromPerson(Person p)`.

Comment: Apologies but it is not necessarily same method 'getLine1()' etc in teacher and student. They can be different. I have updated the question (Method 2)

Comment: If they are different methods, then you can't have a generic method.

Comment: @LouisWasserman and if they are same then how will the generic method look like ? Or do I only need to follow the interface approach as recommended above ?

Comment: Follow the interface approach as recommended above.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, because you are using the same methods (`getLine1()`, `getLine2()`, `getPostcode()`) it's obvious that they are unrelated to the responsibilities of these classes and must reside somewhere else.

As far as these **concerns are connected to postal service** and don't related to the idiosyncratic responsibilities of the classes `Student` and `Teacher` they have to be externalized.

Let's group the behavior related to the post inside the *interface* **PostDetails** (sorry for a clumsy name). And I want to emphasize that it's *highly advisable to use an interface* for this purpose, *not an abstract class like Person*. Tomorrow you may wish to be able to send letters to the organizations but it doesn't make much sense for a class Campany to extend the class Person. *Inheritance creates a tight coupling and can be easily misused*. If you have a choice between an interface and abstract class in the class design interface takes precedence.

Methods of the **PostDetails**  could be *abstract* or *default* (which will probably make sense because the procedure of sending letters except for special cases must be the same).

```
    public interface PostDetails {
        String getLine1();
        String getLine2();
        String getPostcode();
        String getCountryCode();
    }
```

Both Student and Teacher classes must implement the contract defined by the **PostDetails**.

```
    public class Student implements PostDetails {
        // implementation for Student 
    }

    public class Teacher implements PostDetails {
        // implementation for Teacher 
    }
```

As far as method `mapDetails()` isn't bound to any class and meant to use only behavior defined in the **PostDetails** it can accept any implementation of this interface (`Student`, `Teacher`, `Company`, etc).

```
    private Details mapDetails(PostDetails postDetails) {

    }
```

---

**Update**

If there's a need for *two different sets of behavior* related to postal service then it clearly has to be *two* **interfaces** (even if now you have only two classes this decision can bring benefits afterward). And as a consequence, there must be *two overloaded versions* of the `mapDetails()` method that accept as parameter instances of these interfaces.

Comment: Apologies but it is not necessarily same method 'getLine1()' etc in teacher and student. They can be different. I have updated the question (Method 2)

Comment: @newLearner I can see the difference in the usage of `getZipCode()` and `getCountryCode()`. But can you explain the reason for that? Is there any difference in the procedure of how to send a post-mail to a Student and a Teacher? Why?

Comment: Well, I am getting these details from a 3rd party request so I am not sure about that. I am converting these details to my domain object and storing it in DB at my end. So I cannot say why they are sending it this way.

Comment: @newLearner As far as you can send a post-mail to any person in the world like your colleague, your friend, your relative, or even the Norwegian king following the same procedure that means that this process has to be described as something external **unrelated** to the idiosyncratic responsibilities of the classes `Student` and `Teacher`. You can this interface **Mailable**, **Postable** or **PostDetails**, English isn't my native language and I can come up with lots of clumsy names, but I hope you get the idea behind it.

Comment: This method doesn't even have to be generic.  It could just take a `PostDetails` (or whatever you name the interface) as a parameter.

Comment: @rgettman That's a very good point.